# In Star Trek what is the rank just below President of the Federation? And is there a rank above Admiral?

Tags: star-trek

I know there are Admirals, Commandants, Commodores, and more but what is just below Federation President? Is there a such rank? I've wondered for years. And why is there very little mention of the President of the Federation in the tv shows and movies?

Comment: I'm gonna guess vice president. Note that President isn't a military rank. Typically the pres is *also* Commander-in-Chief.

Comment: In fact it's a dupe since I've included the relevant bit. The Federation Council elect a leader. That person is the President of the Federation. There's no-one below him/her/it except the Federation Council, the seats of which are chosen by however the various Federation members want to choose them (e.g. democracy or something else).

Comment: Interestingly, in some of the (non-canon) novels there's mention of a VP; *"Trask here." Vice President Chandra appeared on the screen. "Admiral Trask," the Federation's second-in-command said in a neutral voice. The dark, delicate old woman wore a sari, and she spent a moment adjusting it, as if to impress the admiral with his relative unimportance.* - [Infiltrator](https://www.goodreads.com/book/show/217508.Infiltrator)

Comment: In most navies "rank above admiral" is a bit vague. There are ranks like vice-admiral, rear-admiral, admiral of the fleet, but while they are distinct ranks you can consider them all admirals, and their holders are addressed as "admiral". It's the same with generals in the army. People who have command over admirals have other titles but not usually ranks. "Chief of the defense staff" or "First Lord of the Admiralty" would all be superior to admirals, but don't technically count as ranks. They may hold a rank such as admiral as well.

Comment: Your edit adds a dupe to the list; [What's the command structure at the top of Starfleet?](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/104784/whats-the-command-structure-at-the-top-of-starfleet)

Comment: https://memory-alpha.fandom.com/wiki/Flag_officer

Comment: Thanks again. I keep making that mistake.

Comment: @JordanByrne - Not to worry. There's a lot (a lot) of trek questions. You're gonna stumble over dupes left right and centre.

Comment: Is there a question yet on Andorian hybrids?

Comment: @JordanByrne - Yup; [Are there any Star Trek characters that are hybrids of non-human species?](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/131203/are-there-any-star-trek-characters-that-are-hybrids-of-non-human-species)